# Text_Diff in Pear - Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated

Tags: php, linux, pear

I am tring to use Text_Diff - I have used it before, but it was quite a while ago.
I installed PEAR, then installed Horde Text_Diff..

I had to update my path to pear, but after sucessfully doing that, I now recieve the following messages:

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /usr/local/php54/lib/php/pear/Text/Diff.php on line 383

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /usr/local/php54/lib/php/pear/Text/Diff.php on line 405

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /usr/local/php54/lib/php/pear/Text/Diff.php on line 427

Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /usr/local/php54/lib/php/pear/Text/Diff.php on line 449

Fatal error: Class 'Horde_Text_Diff' not found in /home/key88crazy/reviewmypractice.com/merge/canvis/diff.php on line 10
```

I have looked for solutions for this, and found quite a bit of info about this issue, but nothing has worked yet.

**First Solution:**
I found some info that talks about the & being deprecated, so I tried to remove the & where I was instructed, but that did not work.

Next, I tried to uninstall everything, and re-install. I did this, restarted my web-server, but the issue still remains.

Here is some of my server info:

```
php -v
    PHP 5.4.37 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2015 08:55:06)
    Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
    Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies

cat /etc/*-release
    DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
    DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
    DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"
    NAME="Ubuntu"
    VERSION="12.04.5 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
    ID=ubuntu
    ID_LIKE=debian
    PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)"
    VERSION_ID="12.04"
```

Lastly, is the fatal error for the missing class part of the first issue?

Comment: what is the code that actually produces this error? try to make it as small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed in Text_Diff version 1.2.0; see [the changelog](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/download/1.2.0).